# Need help combining multipile videos playing in vlc using java

Tags: java, video, vlc

- need video combining videos in vlc using java

  i have no clue how im going to code this hope i can get some help with this seeing as i am really unexpirienced with java and code in general.

Answer (score 2):

There are Java bindings for VLC called [VLCJ](http://www.capricasoftware.co.uk/vlcj/index.php).

It's not very hard to play videos and do lots of other things with video in a Java program with VLCJ - see [this tutorial](http://www.capricasoftware.co.uk/vlcj/tutorial1.php), for example.

If you really don't know about Java and programming in general, I'd advise you to first learn that before taking on big and complicated projects.